# how to change color html in selected text using corona webview?

Tags: html, webview, coronasdk

In corona i used showwebpopup method to show my HTML file.in that i have to do some thing like when selected  text that has to ask some  color selection option.then selected text has to be change in that color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Corona you can't use native methods. You can use css and javascript to get what you want.
I think you should see this [jQuery How do i apply CSS to selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809310/jquery-how-do-i-apply-css-to-selected-text) to understand how to get the selected text and change the color of selected text. An alert() would be a simple implementation that will let you choose from some predefined colors http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_confirm

You can also see this discussion
http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/8093/detect-selected-text/p1
(take a look at last post)